# Copy and Paste from Tmux window running inside a terminal on Windows WSL/WSL2

Tags: terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux, copy-paste, tmux, wsl-2

I have been looking for ways to do this for some time: how do I copy text from my Tmux pane - running inside a windows WSL or WSL2 ubuntu (or other linux distro) terminal - to other windows or WSL-Linux applications. I googled this in the past, and I couldn't find a simple solution. I found a ton of complex suggestions none of which worked (and I certainly didn't have the time to turn that into a time consuming project).
How can I instruct `.tmux.conf` to expose its clipboard to the windows clipboard? I can't believe this is so complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this answer is what you are asking for, as I have faced a similar problem yesterday and still today - and I have come to the conclusion that most probably only those with a demoniac intelligence and a lot of free time on their hands are able to tweak Tmux and achieve the goal elegantly.

Having said this, I have found a workaround that works for me, inspired by how I was able to do copy&paste on MS-DOS terminals in Windows in the past.

A picture is probably worth one thousand words here:
[image: enable copy on the Windows Ubuntu terminal. Also works when running Tmux]

Click on the top left icon, `Edit -> Mark`, select text to copy.
Press Enter (or  Click on the top left icon again and go for `Edit -> Copy`)

It did the job for me.

Comment: This is actually helpful. Thank you!